# Count consecutive number of ones in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

If I have the following pandas series:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1])
```

I want a list of counts of consecutive number of ones i.e. in this case the required output is

```
[2,1,2,3]
```

How can I obtain the above output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us try use `cumsum` create the new key

```
s[s==1].groupby(s.eq(0).cumsum()).sum()
1    2
2    1
4    2
5    3
dtype: int64

#s[s == 1].groupby(s.eq(0).cumsum()).sum().tolist()
#[2, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
[len(i) for i in ''.join([str(i) for i in list(s)]).split('0') if '1' in i]
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 2, 3]
```